# 5["abcdef"]; is it correct in c?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Is this instruction correct in c  :

> 5["abcdef"]

If yes, what does it mean ?

I had this question in a c test.

Comment: `a[b] == *(a + b) == *(b + a) == b[a]`

Comment: Think also about `(-1)["hello"+2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, and means the same as `"abcdef"[5]`, which evaluates to `'f'`.

It is because `a[b] == *(a+b) == *(b+a) == b[a]` by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The `[]` operator is commutative; that's the same as `"abcdef"[5]`, which returns `'f'`.